# Getting double data in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I pull student data from 2 databases. 1 from an online SOAP API which can handle async calls and 1 from a local DB with an older services that doesnt support async.
I compare these databases and write the differences in a local sqlDB through EF.

Problem:
I get double entries in my EF DB. He puts the correct data and amount in arrays inside the method, but it looks like once he hits the db.savechanges() he jumps back up a few line and saves again.
I don't even know where this extra thread comes from.

Some code might be still there from numerous tries to solve it. For instance I tried with addrange but I get an error when he tries to add the FullVarianceList.

```
public async Task<bool> FullStudentCompare(string date) //format DD/MM/YYYY
{
    try
    {
        //DB context
        using (var db = new SchoolDbContext())
        {
            //GET DATA
            //SMT (async)
            List<SmtStudent> smtStdudentList = await GetAllSmartschoolStudents();
            //Wisa (sync)
            //on date, or if emty on current systemdate
            List<WisaStudent> wisaList;
            if (date == "")
            {
                wisaList = GetWisaStudentData(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            }
            else
            {
                wisaList = GetWisaStudentData(date);
            }


            //Flags and props needed for DB entry after compare
            bool existsInLocalDb = false;
            List<Variance> vList = new List<Variance>();
            //Full list to add to DB outside foreach
            List<Variance> fullVarianceList = new List<Variance>();
            //Full List of new Students to write to DB outside foreach
            List<DbStudent> fullStudentList = new List<DbStudent>();

            //Compare lists
            foreach (WisaStudent wstd in wisaList)
            {
                //determine correct classCode
                string klasCode;
                if (wstd.klasgroep.Trim() == "Klasgroep 00")
                {
                    klasCode = wstd.klas.Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    klasCode = wstd.klasgroep.Trim();
                }


                //Create SmtStudent object for compare
                SmtStudent tempStd = new SmtStudent(true,
                                                    wstd.voornaam.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.naam.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.stamboeknummer.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.geslacht.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.geboortedatum.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.straat.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.huisnummer.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.busnummer.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.postcode.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.gemeente.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.emailadres.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.GSM_nummer.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.levensbeschouwing.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountmoedervoornaam.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountmoedernaam.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountmoederemailadres.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountmoederGSM_nummer.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountvadervoornaam.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountvadernaam.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountvaderemailadres.Trim(),
                                                    wstd.coaccountvaderGSM_nummer.Trim(),
                                                    klasCode,
                                                    wstd.nationaliteit,
                                                    wstd.geboorteGemeente,
                                                    wstd.geboorteLand
                                                    );


                //Find matching SmtStudent
                SmtStudent smtStd = smtStdudentList.Find(i => i.Internnummer == wstd.stamboeknummer);


                //Find matching Std in local DB
                DbStudent dbStd = await db.Students.Where(i => i.Stamboeknummer == wstd.stamboeknummer).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                //if none exists in the local DB create an entity to update and write to DB
                if (dbStd == null)
                {
                    dbStd = new DbStudent(wstd.voornaam.Trim(),
                                             wstd.naam.Trim(),
                                             wstd.stamboeknummer.Trim(),
                                             wstd.geslacht.Trim(),
                                             wstd.geboortedatum.Trim(),
                                             wstd.straat.Trim(),
                                             wstd.huisnummer.Trim(),
                                             wstd.busnummer.Trim(),
                                             wstd.postcode.Trim(),
                                             wstd.gemeente.Trim(),
                                             wstd.emailadres.Trim(),
                                             wstd.GSM_nummer.Trim(),
                                             wstd.levensbeschouwing.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountmoedervoornaam.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountmoedernaam.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountmoederemailadres.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountmoederGSM_nummer.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountvadervoornaam.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountvadernaam.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountvaderemailadres.Trim(),
                                             wstd.coaccountvaderGSM_nummer.Trim(),
                                             klasCode,
                                             wstd.loopbaanDatum,
                                             wstd.nationaliteit,
                                             wstd.geboorteGemeente,
                                             wstd.geboorteLand
                                             );

                    db.Students.Add(dbStd);
                    fullStudentList.Add(dbStd);
                }
                else
                {
                    existsInLocalDb = true;
                }

                if (smtStd == null)
                {
                    //Std doesn't exist in Smt -> New student
                    dbStd.IsNewStudent = true;
                    dbStd.ClassMovement = true;

                    //remove from wisaList
                    wisaList.Remove(wstd);
                }
                else
                {
                    //clear vlist from previous iterations
                    vList.Clear();

                    //get all properties on the obj, cycle through them and find differences
                    PropertyInfo[] props = smtStd.GetType().GetProperties();

                    vList.AddRange(props.Select(f => new Variance
                    {
                        Property = f.Name,
                        ValueA = f.GetValue(smtStd),
                        ValueB = f.GetValue(tempStd),
                        Checked = false
                    })
                       .Where(v => !v.ValueA.Equals(v.ValueB) && v.ValueB != null)
                       .ToList());


                    //If the users allrdy exists in LocalDb delete all previously recorded variances
                    if (existsInLocalDb)
                    {
                        if (db.Variances.Where(j => j.Student.StudentId.Equals(dbStd.StudentId)).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                        {                            //if the student allready exists we will recreate the variancelist, hence deleting all current items first
                            List<Variance> existingList = db.Variances.Where(j => j.Student.StudentId.Equals(dbStd.StudentId)).ToList();
                            foreach (Variance v in existingList)
                            {
                                db.Variances.Remove(v);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Add new variances if vList is not empty
                    if (vList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //Check if KlasCode is a variance -> set classmovement to true
                        if (vList.Where(i => i.Property == "KlasCode").FirstOrDefault() != null)
                        {
                            dbStd.ClassMovement = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dbStd.ClassMovement = false;
                        }

                        //add the StudentObject to the variance to link them 1-many
                        foreach (Variance v in vList)
                        {
                            v.Student = dbStd;
                            fullVarianceList.Add(v);
                            db.Variances.Add(v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //add the full lists of variances and new students to DB
            //db.Variances.AddRange(fullVarianceList);
            //db.Students.AddRange(fullStudentList);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you're debugging you say you see it 'jumps back up a few lines' and insert again. I can see you're using an `async` method on `FullStudentCompare`. Can I confirm - are you certain that `FullStudentCompare` isn't being called more than once from the browser side? If it's being triggered in JS then add some logging maybe to double check that.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. It is important to understand that EF uses a unit of work pattern where none of the changes to the entities are persisted until SaveChanges is called which explains the "once he hits the db.Savechanges() he jumps back up" phenomenon.
2. When you have a 1 to many relationsship and you assign a collection of entities to a navigation property on another entity and then add that parent entity to the DbContext, EF marks those child entities to be added too. In your case dbStd is added at the line "db.Students.Add(dbStd);" and at the line "v.Student = dbStd;". This is most likely what is causing your duplicates.

Comment: I'm not following on answer 1. I pile up the changes because I've read that calling SaveChanges inside a foreach loop is bad practise. I still don't get why he jumps back up.
For 2. If I add multiple parents with the same child. Doesn't EF check if the child exists on every input?
Even if I delete the line db.Students.Add(dbStd), I get double entries.

Comment: The reason it is bad practice is that it is making a call to the database in each iteration (which is inefficient). EF keeps track of all the changes you make to entities in memory and only when you call SaveChanges does it commit them to the database. See: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html